# How to select annotated data for target class from multiclass public dataset for object detection model training to create TFrecord files?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Am trying to build object detection model using ***[tf2 object detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html)***.
I have two public datasets with multi-class bounding box annotations
***(Annotations are in Pascal-VOC .xml formats)*** from which I wish to create model only for selective classes.

FOR Example:

- Dataset1 has classes ['Tiger', 'Cat', 'Leopard']
- Dataset2 has classes ['Car', 'Auto'. 'Bicycle']

Now here, my **target classes** are **['Tiger', 'Cat', 'Car']**

My question is what is the best method to create the TFrecord files with data having target class?

***Also, some silly solution from my side, Is it possible to?***

1. Merge both datasets as a single dataset.
2. Split as Train-Test.
3. Create a labelmap.pbtxt with my target classes.
4. While generating train & test TFRecord files, parse and select annotations info with reference to my target labelmap classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your questions.
If you are using the `generate_tfrecord.py` script, just add your targeted class to [this function](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/93938849301895fb73909842ba04af9b602f677a/generate_tfrecord.py#L30) and your model will only be trained for these classes and it will ignore other labeled classes in the annotation files.

1. You can merge both datasets as a single dataset but there can be an issue when the Dataset1 objects are present in Dataset2 and they will be unannotated there and the model will treat them as a background there and vice versa.
2. Yes, you can split them.
3. Yes, you can create [labelmap.pbtxt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/kitti_label_map.pbtxt)

Comment: I will try this in my next training iter.